# How to get the full code coverage on a Maven multi-modules project

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, code-coverage, sonarqube

Imagine a multi-modules Maven project, such as the following one:

```
parent
  +- core
  +- main
```

`main` is dependent on the `core` module.

I now write a class `CoreClass` in `core`, with 2 methods: `method1()` and `method2()`.
In `core` tests, I write a test class that will only test `CoreClass.method1()`.

If I run a coverage tool (in my case Cobertura, using `mvn sonar:sonar`), I will find that I get **50%** of test coverage on `CoreClass` (if we imagine that both methods have the same length).

Until now, everything is ok.

Now, in `main` project, I write a test class that will test the `CoreClass.method2()`. So *normally*, I would expect to have **100%** of line coverage on `CoreClass` when I run an analysis on the whole project.

However, I still get my **50%**.

I understand that this is a comprehensive behavior. Indeed, Cobertura will instrument `CoreClass` for coverage analysis *only during the tests execution on the `core` module*, and not on the `main`.
That explains why I still have **50%** of code coverage.

However, my question is to know if there is a way to get the *real* code coverage of `CoreClass` when I am running the tests on all of my modules.

Thanks!

*ps:* I know that in a perfect world, it is not the concern of the `main` module to test the `core` classes. But as you may know, we are not in a perfect world :o)

*Technical information:* Java 1.6, JUnit 4.8.1, Maven 2.0.9 (will be upgraded to 2.2.1 soon, but I don't think it does really matter), Sonar 2.8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java code coverage in Hudson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423405/java-code-coverage-in-hudson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jacoco and sonar and have a single jacoco.exec file result for all modules.
Sonar will use this file and report the correct coverage for each module.
I have use it for a multi module project successfully with Sonar

Comment: Any clue on the exact Maven syntax to use to achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a solution for [jacoco/sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42007488/1313037) and here only for [jacoco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42006741/1313037).