# No jacoco report files generated on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat6, jacoco

Am exploring Jacoco code coverage for my project.After going through various article this is  what i did.

Setup
Tomcat - 6.0.35
jacoco javaagent- 0.6.4

Added these parameter at the start of catalina.sh

CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:/Users/jgupta/Documents/Exported_Software/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/lib/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6300,destfile=/Users/jgupta/Documents/Exported_Software/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/jacoco-report/jacoco.exec"

1) Started tomcat.
2) Browse through the site.
3) Stopped tomcat.

No file is created in jacoco-report. Not even jacoco.exec. Directory is empty.

Please help me out here. There has to something which am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You set

```
output=tcpserver
```

so that means no report will be saved after tomcat stops. To get such report you need to use ant task. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23830837/2555999)

To get file saved on your filesystem use `output=file` or simply delete this parameter since this is by default.