# How to get code coverage for java stand-alone application

Tags: jacoco

I have one java standalone application for which I need to get code coverage report using JaCoCo.

I don't want to use Elipse to run the application as I have jar file.

How to configure JaCoCo for standalone application without using eclipse.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23830837/2555999