# sonarqube displays 0 unit tests data coverage

Tags: unit-testing, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

Trying to see unit test code coverage on sonar. I am using Jacoco code coverage and able to get the code coverage for my project when I execute my code in eclipse. However while running in Jenkins, I get following messages and warnings as NO Tests to run , No Sources to compile

I can the some code coverage report on sonar but for unit tests it shows. How can Sonar display the coverage for unit tests? Also how can I eliminate the warning messages?

Attaching my surefire and jacoco plugins and jebnkins console log

Kindly help

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.4.201312101107</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-unit-test-agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-unit-test-report</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution> 
  </executions>
</plugin> 


    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environment>${env.USER}</environment>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>          
                </configuration>    
            </plugin>

 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Project Test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ project test ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.4.201312101107:prepare-agent (prepare-unit-test-agent) @ project test ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/ray1/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.4.201312101107/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.4.201312101107-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ project test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ project test---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ project test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ project test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ project test ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (run-unit-tests) @ project test ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ project test ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/target/project test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.4.201312101107:report (generate-unit-test-report) @ project test ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ project test ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/target/project test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/ray1/.m2/repository/com/company/taf/project test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/project test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/pom.xml to /Users/ray1/.m2/repository/com/company/taf/project test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/project test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.801 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-14T10:25:50-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/pom.xml to com.company.inner/project test /0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/project test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/ray1/.jenkins/jobs/try10-aprl13/workspace/target/project test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.company.inner/project test /0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/project test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure multi-module Maven + Sonar + JaCoCo to give merged coverage report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031219/how-to-configure-multi-module-maven-sonar-jacoco-to-give-merged-coverage-rep)

Comment: I can see the tests didn't run hence jacoco result file will no be created. Regarding maven + surefire (or failsafe) + jacoco configuration, I do recommend the steps found on this thread:  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031219/how-to-configure-multi-module-maven-sonar-jacoco-to-give-merged-coverage-rep)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, 0.0% coverage & no unit tests count on Sonar dashboard with SonarQube 6.7.2:
Maven : 3.5.2,
Java : 1.8,
Jacoco : Worked with 7.0/7.9/8.0,
OS : Windows

After a lot of struggle finding for correct solution, resolved issue with this configuration my parent pom looks like:

```
 <properties>
            <!--Sonar -->
            <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
            <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>

        </properties>

        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.5</source>
                            <target>1.5</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.0.905</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.9</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                            <append>true</append>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
```

I've tried few other options like *jacoco-aggregate* & even creating a sub-module by including that in parent pom but nothing really worked & this is simple. I see in logs `<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>` is deprecated,but still works as is and seems like auto replaced on execution or can be manually updated to `<sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>` or latest. Once after doing setup start with **mvn clean install** then **mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install** & then do **mvn sonar:sonar** , this is what I've tried please let me know if some other best possible solution available.Hope this helps!! If not please post your question..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this section to your parent pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <!-- Properties to make sure we capture *all* coverage -->
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
</properties>
```