# Not able to get it test coverage in sonarqube

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]I know many people got such similar problem. i show many answars, tried the sample code given on sonar site. that sample is working fine. Also i show following link

[How to configure multi-module Maven + Sonar + JaCoCo to give merged coverage report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031219/how-to-configure-multi-module-maven-sonar-jacoco-to-give-merged-coverage-rep)

But nothing seems working in my case. Its not showing IT Test Coverage in sonarqube though mvn clean intsall is making jacoco folder in site where index.html is having coverage report.
i tried almost every thing on net but not able to resolve issue. 
its a multi module project
I am using

java8.

sonarqube 4.5.6 with java plugin 2.5.1.

maven 3.0.5

please help me resolve this.

**Below is parent module pom file**

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>    
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/../target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>   
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${failsafe.argLine}</argLine>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- automatic label creation -->

    </plugins>  
  </build>
    <!-- Plugin to generate unit test coverage in SonarQube 4.5.x report. -->   

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <use>false</use>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-report-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <alwaysGenerateFailsafeReport>true</alwaysGenerateFailsafeReport>
                <alwaysGenerateSurefireReport>true</alwaysGenerateSurefireReport>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.mar</exclude>
                    <exclude>${jacoco.excludePattern}</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

**Properties in same pom file**

```
   <sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>    <!-- This is the default, put here to be explicit -->
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.java.binaries>${project.basedir}/../target/classes</sonar.java.binaries>
    <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>2.19.1</maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.16</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.16</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
```

mvn clean install is creating jacoco folder with index.html for test coverage but mvn sonar:sonar is not showing it in sonarqube

what mistake i am making.

in mvn sonar:sonar, it builds successfully and one of the line is JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found.

what could be the reason

i seriously feel this a bug with jacoco or sonarqube. May be it would not be compatible with java 8 or something. I tried almost every thing. Many things are deprecated with sonar java plugin 2.5.1. Please help me, i need the solution desperately

Comment: **sonar.dynamicAnalysis** is deprecated with sonar java plugin 2.5.1

Comment: May be combination of plugins would be the problem

Comment: Sample code on line is working good because there is not Integration test cases in it.... Please Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it, and the [sample project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco) works perfectly. Please make sure you do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples.git
cd projects/languages/java/code-coverage/combined ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco
mvn clean package
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Also - not sure if this is related, but you're using a very old version of the SQ Java plugin (2.5.1). I can only advise you to update it to latest version.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice. I did try sample project before. Anyways I am able to resolved it now. I got solution by putting Jacoco plugins with its steps in child pom file. One more thing, my module is one big module so, building it was giving problem so, i used argLine as property rather then in surefire plugin

Answer (score 0):

Well, i am not sure why the above code is not working but i tried same thing bit differently and miracle happened. Let me give the solution what it worked for me.

I removed the below code from parent pom and put it in all child pom. Also since i was using it in child module i used target/jacoco.exec instead of ${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec and same for jacoco-it.exec.

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>    
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                    <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                    <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                    <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>post-integration-test</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <dataFile>target/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Additional information. following plugin which i mentioned in my question is not required if Test coverage is required only in sonar report. If there is requirement for code report separately then its required

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.mar</exclude>
                <exclude>${jacoco.excludePattern}</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```