# Aggregated Coverage or Coverage in the dependent modules not shown in SonarQube + Reports are generated by Jacoco

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin, eclemma

I am running `jacoco` plugin to generate html , xml and `jacoco.exec` reports to measure the coverage of the code tested by my `testNg` tests.

I am successful in the generation of these reports in my local as well as in `Jenkins` and all my unit test results are reflected in `Sonar` and it's showing me the coverage.

My `jacoco.exec` has both results of the coverage in the module and the dependent modules. I have verified this  using `eclemma plugin` for `eclipse`.

I am not getting the coverage results in the dependent modules in Sonar.Does any one what I am doing wrong.

My plugin goes like this

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
 <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
 <executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and my goal is `jacoco:report-aggregate`

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031219/how-to-configure-multi-module-maven-sonar-jacoco-to-give-merged-coverage-rep

Comment: That doesn't seems to be working for getting dependent module coverage

Comment: How do you run your analysis ? if the report is not imported by the analysis of your  dependent module, you won't see the coverage.

Comment: How's that done in sonarqube ?

Comment: The answer has been described here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jacoco/-ipUlIfZfdo/RxmZd1M7CAAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [jacoco plugin coverage in multi-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031219/how-to-configure-multi-module-maven-sonar-jacoco-to-give-merged-coverage-rep)

The following were the mistakes that I did which caused problem form me. In the properties of our pom

```
 <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
```

and in plugin

```
 <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
```

for me, the above statement flushed the `jacoco.exec` in different folders because of difference in maven module hierarchy as a result they never agrregated.

The second point is that the dependent module coverage will be only obtained only if it is a `compile time dependency` to the testing module.