# How to make maven cobertura and surefire plugins work together?

Tags: maven, configuration, cobertura, maven-surefire-plugin

I put the surefire and cobertura plugins in my `pom.xml`, but I can't configure them to work fine. Or cobertura doesn't run or the tests are executes twice.

So, how could I configure the plugins for they run together and just one time?

If I configure in this way, cobertura doesn't run:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</plugin>
```

If I configure in this way, the tests are executes twice:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>cobertura</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What maven goal(s) are you running?

Comment: An alternative is to use Sonar. Runs both these tools with no need to alter your POM file (Plugin is driven by properties, which you can set in your settings file.)

Comment: I've added a part of my pom.xml in the topic

Comment: You can have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732995/running-junits-and-cobertura-with-maven

Answer (score 0):

The tests will run twice - it is just the way it is. See Samuel's comment [running junits and cobertura with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732995/running-junits-and-cobertura-with-maven)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work for tests with cobertura on and surefire off.
Add this to your pom, or put in mvn options for -DuseSystemClassLoader=false

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```