# Run IntelliJ JUnit Tests in Serial

Tags: junit, intellij-idea

I'm using the JUnit runner in IntelliJ to run all tests in a package. When I run my tests in isolation they pass, when I run the entire package some fail, suggesting interplay between the tests. I'd like to force the tests to be run in serial rather than parallel to prove this - can anyone tell me how I can configure this to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests don't run in parallel, at least [not in IDEA 9.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556015/running-junit-tests-in-parallel-in-intellij-idea). Unless you are using IDEA 10 EAP, your problem is different and you need to provide more details to get a good answer.