# How to make JUnit test cases execute in parallel?

Tags: junit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running junit tests in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423627/running-junit-tests-in-parallel)

I found the test cases inside jUnit are executed in sequence, how to make them execute in parallel?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Junit4 provides parallel feature using **ParallelComputer**:

```java
public class ParallelComputerTest {  

   @Test  
   public void test() {      
      Class[] cls={ParallelTest1.class,ParallelTest2.class };  

      //Parallel among classes  
      JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.classes(), cls);  

      //Parallel among methods in a class  
      JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.methods(), cls);  

      //Parallel all methods in all classes  
      JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, true), cls);     
   } 

   public static class ParallelTest1 {  
      @Test public void a(){}  
      @Test public void b(){}  
   }  

   public static class ParallelTest2 {  
      @Test public void a(){}  
      @Test public void b(){}  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Hi, This is really helpful. but, able to run 4 classes only in parallel at a time even though I've more classes in array. Is there any limitation on no of classes running in parallel ?

Comment: What if I don't want to list every single test class (that's seems like a huge pain)? Is there a way to have it pick up every class automatically and run them in parallel?

Comment: Useful but note that exceptions from tests do not get automatically thrown.  You need to check the result of `runClasses`.

Comment: This doesn't work when running on JUnit5. I got long running tests (5-6 sec), and when executing like this in parallell, the tests exit after 100ms. I also tested this exact code, with same results. All tests calls System.out.println(...), and I see no output.

Comment: This won't generate the results of the classes being run in parallel from inside test().

Answer (score -13):

Here is some sample code. This works for me really well. ExecutorService.

```
public class TestCases {
    static ExecutorService exe ;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        test1() ;
        test2() ;
        test3() ;
    }
    public static void test1() {
       exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() ;
       for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
           Test1 test1 = new Test1() ;
           exe.execute(test1) ;
       }
       exe.shutdown() ;
       while(!exe.isShutDown()) {
       }
    }
   //same for test2 and test3
}

public class Test1 implements Runnable {
    public Test1() {
    }
    @Test
    public myTest throws Throwable {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not at all what the question is asking.