# How to run Junit tests in parallel while using page object model?

Tags: junit, testng, parallel-testing

Please share some valuable information. I have not seen any document or standard reference on the internet that explains in detail about this. Even if you have TestNG related information (With Page Object Model), I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Until you are using static variable as driver object or page objects you can run your test scripts in parallel irrespective of whatever unit-test framework you are using.

For Junit3:
You have to use build tools to run it in parallel. You can only run it multi-threaded based on classes and not in methods

For Junit4:

[How to make JUnit test cases execute in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529087/how-to-make-junit-test-cases-execute-in-parallel)

In TestNG: you have thread option in testng.xml itself.