# Running JUnit Tests in parallel with Docker

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, docker

I'm trying to run JUnit Test parallel with Docker. I use a database instance which stored on Amazon AWS RDS. I should run the database instance in a seperate Docker Image. The plan is to run every JUnit test in it's own Docker instance.

Currently I have my jar-File with all my Unit-Tests, including Maven Configuration, Git and Jenkins. I tried to run my jar-File in a Docker Container, which was successful. Are there any existing plugins out there for maybe Jenkins or Maven that can help me execute my tests in parallel?

Any tipps or references would be really appriciated. : )

Thanks,

Comment: is the docker instance on local or in AWS ?

Comment: I only have my MySQL database instance on AWS. Docker is installed local on my machine.

Comment: There is no official maven/docker plugin .. but you may try this http://giallone.blogspot.com.eg/2014/03/integration-testing-with-maven-and.html

Comment: @plitvica       Did you ever find a solution for running in parallel?

Comment: hey ALM, yes i found a soulution for me. I used Maven to integrate the "spotify/docker-client" library to start Docker container from Java. In the JUnit API is a class "ParallelComputer" integrated. This class gives you the possibilty to run tests in parallel. see this example here: [example ParallelComputer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529087/how-to-make-junit-test-cases-execute-in-parallel)