# How does parallelism work in the JUnit test framework?

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver, junit4

How does parallelism work in the [JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) test framework?

How can I run multiple tests in parallel in JUnit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running junit tests in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423627/running-junit-tests-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven and configure it to run your test suite in parallel. You can configure it to run your tests in parallel by method or by classes. See *[Running JUnit tests in parallel with Maven](http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/274-running-junit-tests-in-parallel-with-maven)* for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply start two Runners/JUnitcores in different Threads.