# How to create simple xml and test for parallel testing using junit?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, parallel-processing, selenium-grid

I am using JUnit as a framework and I am trying to set parallel testing, everywhere I lookedonline I can only find examples for TestNG. I have the Grid up and running and I can test cross platform and cross browser but I need to wait for each test to finish in order for the next to start? I just need a basic example to get me started which I think will be of great help to others like me using JUnit.

Comment: I believe out of the box, JUnit does not do parallel runs. You could use this plugin: https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest-core

Comment: What build system do you use to run your tests? If it is Maven, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9498315/95725