# How to run JUnit tests from multiple packages simultaniously in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea

I've multiple packages with absolutely independent pieces of java code. Some packages contain tests that run 5-6 second to complete. Right now, my tests execute sequentially which takes a lot of time to complete all tests in the whole project. However, I quite sure that it's possible to execute tests in package#1/package#2/package#3/.../package#10 simultaneously.

What should I do in order that all my tests from different packages execute at the same time ( without waiting for completion of each other )?

Comment: You can give this plugin a try: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16229-unit-test-parallel-runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out the post and answers at [Running junit tests in parallel in a Maven build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423627/running-junit-tests-in-parallel-in-a-maven-build)

The parallel unit test are supported with Junit 4.7+.  If you are already using maven in your project it may just be easier to handle with the surefire plugin.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer !